# Android - Using AChartEngine, is it possible to zoom in to a specific point upon displaying the graph?

Tags: android, zooming, achartengine

I have a bar graph with 100+ bars and want to zoom in to a specific range upon displaying the graph. For example, when the graph is displayed on the screen I want only the bars 44-49 to be showing. It is important that the users will be able to zoom out to see all 100+ bars as well.

GraphicalView.zoomIn() would work if it allowed me to specify a point to zoom in to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the visible range on the X axis:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(44);
renderer.setXAxisMax(49);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this only sets the range of the x-axis from 44-49. Therefore you cannot zoom out to see any bars outside of that range. For my situation I am wanting to plot all 100 bars but when the graph is displayed, it will be zoomed in on a small range (ex. 44-49) with the ability to zoom/pan to view all of the 100 bars.

Comment: I must have been doing it wrong when I added this in the first time. This is exactly what I needed, thanks!